# Looping Through Items in an Object in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Redux store that has a few objects in it, and I would like to display all of those objects on my webpage using a DOM. But, it's not going through and I can't figure out why not.

Right now I have it set up where I have an empty array called `rows`. Then, I use a forEach loop and add a piece of DOM to the array. Then, I return `{rows}`. But, for some reason, nothing gets displayed.

My reducer:

```
var pushMessageReducer = function (state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RECEIVED_PUSH_MESSAGE':

            var push = JSON.parse(action.PushMessage);

            return _.forEach(push, function (value) {
                console.log(value);
                Object.assign({}, state, value);
            });
    }
};
```

My component:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        console.log("State: " + store.getState());
        var rows = [];
         _.forEach(this.props.pushMessages, function (value, key, push) {

            _.forEach(push, function(notification) {

                //do some logic where, using notification, I set vendorId, problem...

                rows += (
                    <div className="row" key={vendorId}>
                        <Card problem={problem}>
                            <ProgressBar threePercent={threePercent} complete={iOSComplete}</ProgressBar>
                        </Card>
                    </div>);
            })

        });
        return (
            <div id="troi-app">
                {rows}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

It just returns an empty webpage. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First off all you should use `.push` method if you want to add new items ti array, you can not use `+=` concatenation as for String. Second - we need to know how your data looks like - please post piece of them - `this.props.pushMessages`

Comment: Turns out the push was the only issue! Boy do I feel like a fool and a half. Thanks for all your help.